# Merge QGIS projects

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

is there a way to merge different QGIS project-files? For example, i have one project with water supply data. The project organizes the relations of the tables, the styling etc. In another project, the topic gas pipes is organized. One customer wants this topics combined in one project. Is it possible to merge those two existing ones?

Comment: Have a look at the "solution" for a similar problem I am using: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348706/109646

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Option 1 should suit your case better as you could get all layers group in one go.

PS: if you use filesystem for some of your layers and not a database, you may have to change/copy your files for layers and also change data source to make the project "portable" relatively to the project path after applying the recipe from my answer.

**Option 1:**

Open your first project, then go to "Layer" > "Embed Layers and Groups...", select the project you want to borrow/import layers. Select the layers/group you want to import and it's fine.

**Option 2:**

You can also open two QGIS instances and copy from one project to another (right click on layers/group layer tree to choose "Copy layer" or "Copy group") and paste in the layer tree from the other project.

**Option 3:**

In the layer tree, right click on layer, choose "Export", then "Save As Layer Definition File..." from the project you want the layer(s). Then import it in another project with "Layer" > "Add from Layer Definition File..."

**Option 4:**

In the latest QGIS 3.14, you can now drag and drop layers between projects of different QGIS instances e.g https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.14/#feature-allow-dragndrop-layer-across-several-qgis-

If you know other ways, curious to know how.

Comment: brilliant! thank you, option 3 was the only one i came up with and that would have been a hustle!

Comment: ok well, this works perfect for the layer styling. Appart from that it unfortunately imports not the "project" settings - how the layers are related (1:n relations etc) - which is important as some virtual fields depend on that relations

Comment: Not aware of friendly way to do it. Could be possible to copy from projet to another by using PyQGIS to export relations as a config and then import them in your other project with PyQGIS also, after layers/group import.

Comment: My PyQGIS abilities are rather weak but i will try and research a bit how this would work. I'll update the question if i find something

Comment: Maybe, you should ask another question only for the PyQGIS part instead of here.